# Dynamically create UILabels in UITableView from a json in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Iam trying to create this design [image]

from following json

```
 details =     (
                (
                        {
                subtitle = "One";
                title = 1;
            },
                        {
                subtitle = "two";
                title = "2";
            },
                        {
                subtitle = "three";
                title = "3";
            }
        ),
                (
                        {
                subtitle = "one_two";
                title = "1_2";
            },
                        {
                subtitle = "two_two";
                title = "2_2";
            }
        )
    );
```

I have tried following code and its not showing any UILables

```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] ;

        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        int i = 0;
        NSUInteger nLabels = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] count];
        UILabel *label;
        float x =self.tableView.frame.size.width/nLabels;

        for (i = 0; i < nLabels; i++) {
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10 + (i * x), cell.frame.origin.y, 40, cell.frame.size.height)] ; //replace 40 with desired label width
            label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            // set the label text here
            label.text=@"treWT";
            [label setNumberOfLines:0];
            [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Now i can see simulator in this way
[image]

still its not aligned
Pls help me

Comment: What is the value of `nLabels`?

Comment: temp i hard coded values like this "  label.text=@"treWT";
'

Comment: First add debug to see your cell is nil or not nil. If it not nil, the configure cell code is never been called
Please paste the code that configure cell outside the `if (!cell)` clause. it will not run the code inside because the cell is not nil .

Comment: Why do people ignore the deprecation warnings?  There's a dequeue method that is guaranteed to return a cell.  Use it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code for label alignment :

```
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    int i = 0;
    NSUInteger nLabels = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] count];
    UILabel *label;
    float w =self.tableView.frame.size.width/nLabels;
    float x = 0; 

    for (i = 0; i < nLabels; i++) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, cell.frame.origin.y, w, cell.frame.size.height)] ; //replace 40 with desired label width
        label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        // set the label text here
        label.text=@"treWT";
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
         x += w;
    }
```

Comment: @Bangalore Keep It up Bro :P

Answer (score 0):

Remove `if(!cell)` as cell is not `nil`. It will not execute condition.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] ;

    int row = [indexPath row];
    int i = 0;
    int nLabels = [[rowData objectAtIndex:row] count];
    UILabel *label;


    for (i = 0; i < nLabels; i++) {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + (i * 40), cell.frame.origin.y, 40, cell.frame.size.height)] ; //replace 40 with desired label width
        label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        // set the label text here
          label.text=@"treWT"; //temp text 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    }


return cell;
}
```

Comment: but how do i align them?

Comment: label was not displaying becoz i added custom label in ui

Comment: but in your code you are adding UILabel, where is custom label?

Comment: in storyboard by mistake i added another cell